# spaces in a string python

Tags: python

How do you detect if there are 2 consecutive spaces in a string in Python?

For example, with the input string:

```
Hello   there
```

I'd like to detect the two spaces and return `True`.

I know you can use `split` and `join` to fill in the consecutive spaces, but how do you detect them?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to find two or more *consecutive* spaces:

```
if "  " in s:
    # s contains two or more consecutive space
```

If you want to find two or more spaces anywhere in the string:

```
if s.count(' ') >= 2:
    # s contains two or more spaces
```

Comment: Note that this detects two *or more* spaces e.g., it will return ``True`` for three consecutive spaces. If you're just trying to detect the presence of multiple spaces so you can clean the string up this is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution is achieved by using regular expressions, for checking if there are *two or more consecutive spaces* anywhere in the input string. For instance:

```
import re
if re.search('\s{2,}', s):
    # s contains two or more consecutive spaces
```

If you only need to check if there are *exactly* two spaces anywhere in the string, you're better off using @Mark Byers 's solution, as is simpler.

Comment: Why are regular expressions better if there are more than two words? What does the number of words have to do with it? The question was asking about exactly two spaces, in which case `in` is definitely superior to using a regular expression (especially for a beginner just learning to program, which I infer based on the fundamental nature of the question)